# Como posso verificar algoritmos livres de bloqueio (lock-free)?

Tags: paralelismo, concorrência

Existe alguma ferramenta/processo/metodologia disponível para provar que um programa concorrente mas que não utiliza locks em suas regiões crítica está correto?